# Create a guessing number game in java without break, continue and return in a loop

Tags: java

I am writing a guessing game. The game is supposed to pick a random number between 1 and 99 (inclusive) and then after you pick the good number you get a "success" message. I can only do 5 tries. I think I need to do some `try-catch`, `if-else` and loops to make sure to get all the exceptions. Not writing an `int` gives you an `InputMismatchException` and lets you try again but you don't lose a "life" you still got 5/5 or 3/5 tries (it depends on the progress you've done in the game). Same thing with numbers over the limits.

Example:

```
(1/5) 0 < ? < 100 : 50
(2/5) 50 < ? < 100 : 75
(3/5) 50 < ? < 75 :
```

(Some parts are in French)

Thank you for your time!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovt1m.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/abtPa.png

```java
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();
        int nbGenere = r.nextInt(100); 
        int nb1; // first number from user
        int nb2; // second number from user
        int borneMini; // minimum
        int borneMax; // max
        boolean valide1 = false; // variable do #1
        boolean valide2 = false; // variable do #2
        System.out.println(nbGenere);
        System.out.print("You got 5 tries to find a number 1 and 99 (inclusive)\n(1/5) 0 < ? < 100: ");
        do { // do #1
            try {
                nb1 = scan.nextInt();
                borneMini = 0;
                borneMax = 100;
                valide1 = nb1 > borneMini && nb1 < borneMax;
                if (!valide1)
                    System.out.print("Enter a valide number 1\n(1/5)" + borneMini + " < ? < " + borneMax + ": ");
                else if (nb1 == nbGenere)
                    System.out.print("Success!");
                else if (nb1 < nbGenere)
                    System.out.print("(2/5) " + nb1 + " < ? < 100: ");
                else
                    System.out.print("(2/5) 0 < ? < " + nb1 + ": ");
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.print("Enter a valide number 2\n(1/5)\" + borneMini + \" < ? < \" + borneMax + \": ");
                scan.nextLine();
            }
            do { // #2
                try {
                    nb2 = scan.nextInt();
                    if (nb1 < nbGenere)
                        borneMini = nb1;
                    else
                        borneMini = 0;

                    if (nb1 > nbGenere)
                        borneMax = nb1;
                    else
                        borneMax = 100;

                    valide2 = ((nb1 > nb2 || nb1 < nb2) && nb1 > borneMini && nb1 < borneMax);
                    if (!valide2)
                        System.out.print("Enter a valide number 3\n(2/5)" + borneMini + " < ? < " + borneMax + ": ");
                    else if (nb2 == nbGenere)
                        System.out.print("success!");
                    else if (nb1 > nb2 )
                        System.out.print();
                } catch (InputMismatchException f) {
                    System.out.print("Enter a valide number 4\n(2/5");
                }
            } while (!valide2);
        } while (!valide1);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question here?

Comment: How should I start doing it because I'm a bit lost ngl. Just an hint would really help.

Comment: Just a word of advice if you want to succeed in your course and career. Form a study group with your peers and learn together. I can't stress how valuable this is as a student, and I would avoid posting homework problems. Rather, ask specific questions that could possibly help you arrive to a solution. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

```java
int nbGenere = r.nextInt(100);
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) this method may return 0 (zero) which is not what you want. Better to use method [nextInt(int, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/RandomGenerator.html#nextInt(int,int)), i.e.

```java
int nbGenere = r.nextInt(1, 100);
```

You only need one `do-while` loop and you need a variable to keep track of the number of guesses.

If the user-entered number is not within the valid range, you can throw an [exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) since you use the same handling for both a non-number and a number that is not within the acceptable range.

```java
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();
        int nb1; // number from user
        int borneMini = 0; // minimum
        int borneMax = 100; // maximum
        int nbGenere = r.nextInt(borneMini + 1, borneMax); 
        boolean valide1 = false;
        boolean valide2 = false; // variable do #1
        System.out.println(nbGenere);
        System.out.println("You have 5 tries to find a number between 1 and 99 (inclusive).");
        int tries = 5; // total guesses allowed
        int attempt = 1; // guess number
        do { // do #1
            System.out.printf("(%d/%d) %2d < ? < %3d : ", attempt, tries, borneMini, borneMax);
            try {
                nb1 = scan.nextInt();
                valide1 = nb1 > borneMini && nb1 < borneMax;
                if (!valide1) {
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                }
                else if (nb1 == nbGenere) {
                    System.out.println("Success!");
                    valide2 = true;
                }
                else if (nb1 < nbGenere) {
                    attempt++;
                    borneMini = nb1 - 1;
                }
                else {
                    attempt++;
                    borneMax = nb1 + 1;
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.printf("Enter a valid number between %d and %d.%n", borneMini, borneMax);
                scan.nextLine();
            }
        } while (!valide2 && attempt <= tries);
        if (!valide2) {
            System.out.println("Better luck next time. The mystery number was " + nbGenere);
        }
    }
}
```

Output from a sample run:

```
65
You have 5 tries to find a number between 1 and 99 (inclusive).
(1/5)  0 < ? < 100 : 500
Enter a valid number between 0 and 100.
(1/5)  0 < ? < 100 : 50
(2/5) 49 < ? < 100 : 75
(3/5) 49 < ? <  76 : 62
(4/5) 61 < ? <  76 : 68
(5/5) 61 < ? <  69 : 65
Success!
```

Another sample run:

```
64
You have 5 tries to find a number between 1 and 99 (inclusive).
(1/5)  0 < ? < 100 : 50
(2/5) 49 < ? < 100 : foo
Enter a valid number between 49 and 100.
(2/5) 49 < ? < 100 : 75
(3/5) 49 < ? <  76 : 8
Enter a valid number between 49 and 76.
(3/5) 49 < ? <  76 : 62
(4/5) 61 < ? <  76 : 67
(5/5) 61 < ? <  68 : 66
Better luck next time. The mystery number was 64
```

Answer (score -1):

not super sure why you have two do while loop but what you are looking for probably look sth like this

```
        public void gameLoop(Scanner scanner, int life){
        int input;
        int number;
        int lifeRemaining = life;
        do {
            try {
                input = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println("Wrong input! Input only integer numbers please: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            //check if valid based on game rule
            if(!inputCheck(input)){
                //do sth
            }else{
                //only comes here if input is valid
                if(input > number){
                    //print sth
                    lifeRemaining--;
                }
                if(input<number){
                    //print sth
                    lifeRemaining--;
                }
                if(input==number){
                    //print sth
                    lifeRemaining--;
                }
            }
        }while(lifeRemaining>0);
        //game over
   }
```

Comment: I can't put continue, break or return in the loop (teacher don't want to) and we didn't learn yet Integer.parseInt, e.getMessage, inputCheck(input) (don't know whta that means).

Comment: Ah my bad the last three continues aren't really necessary I just added them out of habit. the first continue can be avoided by putting the remaining code into else. ``` inputCheck``` is meant to be a method you write yourself that check whether the user input is valid base on game rule. Integer.parseInt is there because I used ```scanner.nextLine()``` instead of ```scanner.nextInt()``` which returns a String. And I need to cast it to int to be able to use it as one.